# What does building each pixel mean in flutter terms

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, native

I have started learning flutter and reading about it and one thing that comes up, again and again, is that flutter owns every pixel on the screen or every pixel is controlled by flutter but I didn't fully understand what that really means. 
Also, What is the opposite of that. I mean what if flutter does not own every pixel on the screen and how would that look like. Is there anything like that already?

I have no deeper knowledge of the topic as I am new to mobile development so maybe someone can explain in simple terms about what all the owning every pixel thing mean?

Comment: flutter owns every pixel on the screen

Comment: @hesam yeah, but What does that mean and how it achieves that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What that means is, the native world comes with built-in pre-styled components. But Flutter doesn't use them.

Flutter asks the native platform a "Canvas", and then recreate these native components by drawing by itself on that canvas.

The consequences are that Flutter is not bound by the restrictions of the platform. We can have Cupertino components on Android, or Material design before Android 4.0.0.

This also means that your typical Android debug tool won't work. If you activate Android's layout debugging on a Flutter app, you won't see much.